# Looking for code sample for a Grouped UITableView that is populated from an an NSMutableArray of objects (NOT FROM CORE DATA and NSFetchedResults)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, nsmanagedobject

Looking for code sample for a Grouped UITableView that is populated from an an NSMutableArray of objects (NOT FROM CORE DATA and NSFetchedResults).

Consider a rolodex of people contact information and the UITableView is grouped by the State where the people are from.  Again, these people objects are stored in an nsmutablearray.

Does anyone have an example at the ready?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might find some examples [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Comment: Thanks, meggar.  I had seen the regions/timezones example before but had not recognized it as one that did grouped tableviews sans core data.  I should be good to go.